# Fractal Terrain always has a Mountain on the bottom

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working on a project, and I'm almost done with the  terrain generation, but I have a small problem. The bottom of the terrain is always a mountain. Nothing I have tried has worked. Any efficiency improvements are welcome as well.

Here is my algorithm:

```
private void generateTerrain() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int seed = rand.nextInt(panel.maxSeed - panel.minSeed) + panel.minSeed;
    int offset = 10000;
    int sideLength = panel.mapSize - 1;
    int halfSideLength;
    int average;
    int yTop;
    int yBottom;

    panel.map[0][0] = seed;
    panel.map[panel.mapSize - 1][0] = seed;
    panel.map[0][panel.mapSize - 1] = seed;
    panel.map[panel.mapSize - 1][panel.mapSize - 1] = seed;

    while (sideLength > 0) {
        halfSideLength = sideLength / 2;

        for (int x = 0; x < panel.mapSize - 1; x += sideLength) {
            for (int y = 0; y < panel.mapSize - 1; y += sideLength) {
                average = panel.map[x][y]
                        + panel.map[x + sideLength][y]
                        + panel.map[x][y + sideLength]
                        + panel.map[x + sideLength][y + sideLength];
                average /= 4;

                if (rand.nextBoolean()) {
                    average += rand.nextInt(offset);
                } else {
                    average -= rand.nextInt(offset);
                }

                panel.map[x + halfSideLength][y + halfSideLength] = average;

                yTop = y - halfSideLength;
                yBottom = y + halfSideLength;

                if (yTop < 0) yTop = y + halfSideLength;
                if (yBottom > panel.mapSize - 1) yBottom = y - halfSideLength;

                average = panel.map[x][y]
                        + panel.map[x + sideLength][y]
                        + panel.map[x + halfSideLength][yTop]
                        + panel.map[x + halfSideLength][yBottom];
                average /= 4;


                panel.map[x + halfSideLength][y] = average;
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < panel.mapSize; x += sideLength) {
            for (int y = 0; y < panel.mapSize - 1; y += sideLength) {
                int xRight = x + halfSideLength;

                if (xRight > panel.mapSize - 1) xRight = x - halfSideLength;

                average = panel.map[x][y]
                        + panel.map[x][y + sideLength]
                        + panel.map[xRight][y + halfSideLength]
                        + panel.map[xRight][y + halfSideLength];
                average /= 4;

                panel.map[x][y + halfSideLength] = average;

            }
        }

        offset *= 0.5;
        sideLength /= 2;
        if (offset < 1) {
            offset = 1;
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < panel.mapSize - 1; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < panel.mapSize - 1; y++) {
            panel.map[x][y] = (int) ((panel.colors.length - 1) - panel.map[x][y] / 500);
            if (panel.map[x][y] < 0) {
                panel.map[x][y] = 0;
            } else if (panel.map[x][y] > 20) {
                panel.map[x][y] = 20;
            }
        }
    }
    panel.drawImage();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you have incorporated some of the suggestions I made to your [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228244/diamonds-and-squares-algorithm-not-working/30230597#30230597).

The solution I have proposed has three loops. You have joined the first two loops, but the limits of the loops are different. That means you don't set values for the bottom line. (These are probably initialised to zero, so they come out as mountains in the final map.)

It's a [fence-post error](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FencePostError). To illustrate:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     | 
|     |     |     |     | 
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     | 
|     |     |     |     | 
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     | 
|     |     |     |     | 
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     | 
|     |     |     |     | 
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

In this 4×4 map,

- the first loop treats the centre points for the 4×4 squares,
- the second loop treats the midpoints of the 4×5 horizontal lines and
- the third loop treats the midpoints of the 5×4 vertical lines.

Another issue is that the last loop that calculates colour indices from the height values should include the map values on the right and bottom borders, but maybe you just need them as auxiliary values for terrain creation.

Comment: Thanks for the quality anwer, but the array does include those values. `mapSize` is the size of the array, which starts at 0, so if I set the size to 65 i need to check 0-64.

Comment: The array includes a row at index `mapSize - 1`, but it doesn't set the according values. For a step of 32, your loop visits rows 0, 32, but not 64, because `64 < panel.mapSize - 1` is false and the loop terminates. I suggest that you initialise the whole map to a high value, say 10,000, first. I bet you'll see that the ottom has a lot of sea.

Comment: Oh, that was a typo, I forgot to remove that minus one from the code. Thanks for the catch

Comment: I think you should separate the loop. Finding the centre point will access `y + sideLength` and if you include row 64, it will try to access row 96, which is out of bounds.